# Is it possible to assign high priority to a certain route in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, http, kestrel-http-server

A website in ASP.NET Core 7 on Kestrel handles thousands of API requests per second.

I would like to have an endpoint `/API/something_important` that would have higher priory over handling all other requests. Somehow a request to this endpoint would be able to skip to all other requests waiting in http queue to make sure it's processed with urgency.

How could this be done?

Comment: There isn't anything built in to do what you're asking, instead, if certain HTTP requests have different SLAs, you can look at handling this at the infrastructure level, such as having a load-balancer route these requests to a different backend group.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this issue at the architectural level. For example, you can deploy the endpoint to another server (or servers with load balancing module).
So, it is better to separate the endpoint from other endpoints. By using load balancers, you can set priority to route request to multiple servers. if you use Nginx for load balancing, you can find different algorithms:
https://www.nginx.com/faq/what-are-the-load-balancing-algorithms-supported/